# How can I automatically calculate start and end date calculation based on days remaining?

Tags: excel, date, increment

I have a table like so:

```
     A           B         C
----------------------------------
| Days Rem |   Start  |   End    |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   0.94   |  Mar 31  |  Mar 31  | 
|----------|----------|----------|
|   0.38   |  Mar 31  |  Apr 01  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   0.75   |  Apr 01  |  Apr 01  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   0.5    |  Apr 01  |  Apr 02  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   1.5    |  Apr 02  |  Apr 03  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   1.0    |  Apr 03  |  Apr 04  |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   1.0    |  Apr 04  |  Apr 07  |
----------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is to only have to manually populate the first Start value and then have End values and the next Start values automatically increment accordingly. At the moment, all of my start dates are manually entered, and my end dates are calculated like so:

```
=WORKDAY(B1,A1)
```

It'd be cool to do this, because then I could introduce a Lag column to influence the Start Dates accordingly...

I'd like to know the best way to do this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your 'Days Rem' column is populated manually, so the easiest way I see would be to have each cell in the Start column reference the preceding cell in the End column.

So you would have `B2=C1`, `B3=C2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the read and the feedback!  The thing that's got me is the fact that A2, A3 and A4 all fall across April 1, but they add up to a total of 1.07 which makes me think that C4 should be April 2.  Is that right, or am I nuts?

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing in the `WORKDAY` function, it's hard to give you a decent answer, but I would speculate that some of that extra got eaten up by March 31, but again I can't be certain.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  Here's an example of what I've got thus far: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkg1lemn4mticoj/Project%20Plan%20Example.xlsx

Hopefully the columns are self-explanatory, but let me know.  My thought is to be able to move the start dates around via positive or negative values in the "Lag" column.

Comment: After browsing the Excel documentation, I think I figured out the trouble you're having; according to [this](https://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/workday-function-HP010343038.aspx), the second argument to `WORKDAY` is truncated if it's not an integer, so you're losing a ton of precision. I don't know Excel's Datetime functions well enough to know if there's a substitute, but I would advise defining your own.